# converting a list containing tab separated values to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data like below. How can I convert it to a pandas dataframe?

I tried something like this but it does not work.

```
pd.DataFrame([x.split('\t') for x in text])
```

```
text= ['FA874296 31DEC2024 1519 12 UF_128 UF_128 0 0 0 0 0\n',
 'FA874296 31MAR2025 1519 13 UF_128 UF_128 0 0 0 0 0\n',
 'FA874296 30JUN2025 1519 14 UF_128 UF_128 0 0 0 0 0\n',
 'FA874296 30SEP2025 1519 15 UF_128 UF_128 0 0 0 0 0\n',
 'FA874296 31DEC2025 1519 16 UF_128 UF_128 0 0 0 0 0\n']
```

Comment: Where did that list come from? If you've just read a file, you could use `pandas.read_csv` directly on the file without the interim list.

Comment: that list is from a file without extension which I read using f = open(path, "rt")
text = f.readlines()

Comment: In that case, I think `df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=" ")` (or perhaps `sep="\t"` if it really is tab separated) should do.

Comment: excellent space separated just did the trick. Now that I know it sounds stupid to not try that.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the fields are space delimited, not tab. Also, the newline will mess up the last line. Assuming you don't need full CSV support (where you may need to escape spaces internal to a column), you could do

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x.strip().split(' ') for x in text])
```

Comment: @itthrill - that's what the `x.strip()` part is for. It will strip any leading or trailing newline or whitespace.